# MIPS Assembler "bne" Branch Address

Tags: mips

I am working on an homework assignment which asks to translate the below MIPS instructions (highlighted in blue) into decimal, binary and hex equivalences, as well as to provide the local counter and program counter for each instruction. My answers are below in the white cells right below each instruction.

For the instruction bne $t9, $zero, next, I was told that the branch address is slightly off. Below steps are what I did to arrive at the answer:

1. Converted the bne opcode into decimal 5 according to the MIPS Green Sheet and then converted to its binary and hex equivalence
2. Converted the rs ($t9) and rt ($zero) into the decimals 25 and 0 according to the Green Sheet, respectively. Then, I converted them into their binary and hex equivalence.
3. Converted immediate code for the label "next" using the formula: PC = PC + 4 + BranchAddr. I rearranged the formula to Next Address = Current Address + 4 + Offset Address * 4 and finally to Offset Address = (Next Address - Current Address - 4) / 4. The label "next" is originally located at 0x04. Since the "bne" is currently located at 0x18, it is pointing at the address 0x1C. Thus the offset address is 0x04 (4 x 16 = 4) - 0x1C (1 x 16 + 12 = 28) = -24, the different is divided by 4 which results in -6. The result is then converted to it binary and hex equivalences.

I am not sure what is off here. Any help would be very much appreciated.

[image: MIPS Instruction Assembler]

Comment: That `bne` looks good to me.

Comment: (As it is a conditional branch, I would say it has two possible PC values after execution: 0x1c and 0x4.)